# Understanding Yii::import method

Tags: php, yii, components

As said in the Yii documentation

> Imports a class or a directory.
>
> Importing a class is like including the corresponding class file. The
>   main difference is that importing a class is much lighter because it
>   only includes the class file when the class is referenced the first
>   time.
>
> Importing a directory is equivalent to adding a directory into the PHP
>   include path. If multiple directories are imported, the directories
>   imported later will take precedence in class file searching (i.e.,
>   they are added to the front of the PHP include path).

Consider the following code snippet:

```
Yii::import('application.components.document');
echo "This is included file:";
foreach(get_included_files() as $value){
    echo "<div>".$value."</div>";
}
```

Here is an output:

```
Z:\home\localhost\www\index.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\yii\framework\yii.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\yii\framework\YiiBase.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\yii\framework\base\interfaces.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\yii\framework\base\CModule.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\yii\framework\base\CComponent.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\web-config.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\yii\framework\logging\CLogger.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\yii\framework\web\CHttpRequest.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\yii\framework\base\CApplicationComponent.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\yii\framework\collections\CMap.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\yii\framework\web\CUrlManager.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\protected\controllers\tranController.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\yii\framework\web\CController.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\yii\framework\web\CBaseController.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\protected\controllers\tranAction.php
Z:\home\localhost\www\yii\framework\web\actions\CAction.php
```

But this class imported after I'm using it like `Yii::app()->document;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function Yii::import don't include file, but simple add path to $_import array, look [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/YiiBase.php#L263).

Comment: Thank for your answer. But I want to clarify one thing: If we're applying to component as `Yii::app()->document;` then `__get`  magic method is invoked. This method invoke `getComponent` method which is using `_componentConfig` array, but not using `_import`. So why without `Yii::import('application.components.document');` we can't using `Yii->app()->document` component?

Comment: I think we can, because we specify class component on config file: document=>array('class'=>'application.components.document')